# QT XmlListModel and Listview viewing data

Tags: qt, qml, sailfish-os

I am trying to parse xml and view it in program:

```
<list>
    <item>
    This i want
    </item>
    <item>
    This i want 2 </item>
    <item>This i want</item>
    <item>This i want</item>
    <item>This i want</item>
    <item>This i want</item>
    <item/>
    <item/>
    <item/>
    </list>
```

With XmlListModel like this and view with ListModel:

```
XmlListModel {
            id: itemmodel
            source: page.dataURL
            query: "/list"

            XmlRole {
                name: "item"
                query: "item/string()"
            }
            }
  SilicaListView {
       width: 180; height: 300
       model: itemmodel
       delegate: Text { text: item }
   }
```

When I run this it Qt creator says: "Unable to assign [undefined] to QString".
What I am doing wrong? 
I am making app to Sailfish and this silicalistview is same as listview in qt.
My goal is to view them like this:

```
This I want
This I want 2
```

and so on.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue I think is that you only have one `<list>` element and then all your `<item>` are in the same parent. So your query is looking for each `<list>` in your XML (only one) and then it prints only the first `<item>` element.

Here is some code changing the `XmlRole` and the `query` that should work. I put the XML directly into the `xml` property to simplify:

```
XmlListModel {
  id: itemmodel
  xml: "<list><item>This i want</item><item>This i want2</item></list>"
  query: "/list/item"
  XmlRole {
      name: "item"
      query: "string()"
  }
}
ListView {
   width: 180; height: 300
   model: itemmodel
   delegate: Rectangle {
     height: 40
     width: 100
     color:"red"
     Text {
       text: item
     }
   }
 }
```